# Recover files from Damaged Partitiohn

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I was using Ubuntu 10.10 with VirtualBox for my virtual machines. I think my hdd has some bad sectors because after one reset Ubuntu failed to start. After running fsck -y from live CD some changes were made to my partition. I tried to run testdisk from another PC to this harddrive but I can't access the old Linux partition. It appears deleted partition after deep scan. How can I recover my ova files? Testdisk also gives me a warning about number of heads/cylinder mismatches.

Comment: I know. I already upgraded to supported version to a new harddrive, but I must recover the virtual machine files from the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "R-Linux", it might recover your data and it's got nice GUI:

http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/Download.shtml

There's probably also a way to repair broken partition, but I would recover data to another partition with R-Linux first (just in case).

After doing that backup, run DOS tool "HDAT2" from boot disc (like Hiren's Boot CD) and see if those were really bad sectors (it might even fix them for you - but don't count that drive will not fail again).

Comment: Hi Ted! Tnx. I am not interested about the old drive. Already replaced it. Only the virtual machine files it's very important to recover. I am now scanning with R-Linux.

Comment: Ted! I recovered 2 vmdk files from 3. I am now looking for the third one. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure :) R-Studio (& R-Linux) also helped me many times over the years. Yeah, damage can change paths and names of some files...

Comment: Nice answer for the EXT part, but regarding Hiren's Boot CD that is a huge collection of highly pirated software... Is there any legal way of doing the same thing you would recommend instead?

Comment: I thought that normal Hiren's is compiled of free or trial soft... I realize that there is also a pirated edition with most programs unlocked, but that's unofficial and done by somebody else. However HDAT2 which I recommended seems to be free, there's an ISO to download on their website: http://www.hdat2.com/